Tomcat is shutting down if my Jenkins job takes too long
I run Jenkins as a webapps inside a Tomcat on a Ubuntu machine.
In case one Jenkins build task takes longer than one hour the Tomcat is shutting down (without any user action).
If I exclude some work from the gradle build task (don't build all Android product flavors), which reduces the build time to less than one hour, it works fine. (This is not the solution because I need all product flavors.)
Some Environment information :

Linux Ubuntu 5.15.x
The Linux machine has enough memory
The Tomcat has enough memory (JVM)
The Tomcat is started at boot time systemd
The Jenkins build task starts a gradle build file with its own GradleDaemon (Version 8.2)
No other users working on the machine

I have no idea why the Tomcat is shutting down.
Any idea how to find the reason why the Tomcat is shutting down ?
